# Calling query.locate in dwscript

Tags: delphi, dwscript

Is it possible to call a procedure that has a parameter of type set in dwscript?
I am exposing TDataSet and TADOQuery using ExposeClassToUnit.

```
var ScriptUnit : TdwsUnit;
ScriptUnit.ExposeClassToUnit(TDataSet, TComponent);
ScriptUnit.ExposeClassToUnit(TADOQuery, TDataSet);
```

The script that I cannot call is

```
if ADOQuery2.Locate('AccCode',  ADOQuery1.FieldByName('AccCode').AsString, []) then
```

I tried using 0 instead of []. This does compile but then gives me the message as below.

```
Runtime Error: VAR and OUT arguments must match parameter type exactly in Run
```

All help appreciated

Comment: Sets are currently not supported, you'll have to emulate them with boolean operations and write the event handler.

Comment: Ok, thanks Eric. I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Eric, I'm now supporting Delphi sets to script by creating arrays of an enumerated type. This works nicely using Delphi RTTI on the call from script to Delphi.